# Angular 16 run library in local watch

Tags: angular, shared-libraries, watch

I have an Angular 16 project and I also developed an Angular 16 library When I launch my local librarian and install it in my Angular project I have the following error:

```
NG0203: inject() must be called from an injection context such as a constructor,
factory function, field initializer, or a function used  with runInjectionContext.
For more information, visit https://angular.io/errors/NG0203
```

I launch it with a `ng build --watch`

Comment: If you want help with your code, it's impossible for anyone to help you if you don't show the code you want help with. In order to help you we need a [Minimal Reproducible Example](//stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) directly in your question. Please [edit your question](//stackoverflow.com/posts/77316589/edit) and add some code to your question.